# How to get GitExtensions installed on Visual Studio 2010 Beta 2?

Tags: git, visual-studio-2010, git-extensions

How do I manually install GitExtensions as a plugin for Visual Studio 2010 Beta 2? There is no automatic option in the present installer, only plugin options for Visual Studio 2005/2008.

Answer (score 1):

I think the plugin architecture is different for 2010 (not 100% sure on that, but fairly certain), so they might need to alter their code to suit.

The plugin's not really necessary though - personally I find it easier to use GIT outside of VS altogether.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to try it right now, but it seems that it;s the following package:

http://code.google.com/p/gitextensions/

Regards,
Herber