# Working with Git in Visual Studio 2010 beta 2

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

[GitExtensions doesn't yet support 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634080/how-to-get-gitextensions-installed-on-visual-studio-2010-beta-2). What do I in the meantime?

I want something that handles moving/renaming files from within the IDE, similar to Ankh for SVN.

Comment: Both GitExtensions and Git Source Control Provider support Visual Studio 2010 (its out of beta now).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Git Source Control Provider](http://gitscc.codeplex.com/), an extension that plugs into Visual Studio.

Its 100% compatible with Visual Studio 2010, and supports moving/renaming files from both the IDE, and from Windows Explorer (it automatically detects any moves/renames).

Instructions to get going:

1. Download from [Git Source Control Provider](http://gitscc.codeplex.com/) and install.
2. In Visual Studio, "Tools..Options..Source Control..Plug In Selection" then Select "Git Source Control Provider".
3. Add a few files into GIT source control.
4. Now, right click on any file in your solution, and select "Git..Pending Changes".

   - If you move/rename the file from within Visual Studio, you'll see the move pop up in the "GIT Pending Changes Window".
   - If you move/rename the file from within Windows Explorer, you'll see the move pop up in the "GIT Pending Changes Window".

To check in, in the "GIT Pending Changes Window", select "Commit" to commit the changes.

Right click on any file, and select

Answer (score 0):

I think in the mean time you should use the standalone GitExtension application to manage the repository.

Comment: Or, you know, use VS 2008. There's really no need to be using 2010... although I'm a bit of a hypocrit since I'm using it too and was delighted when I discovered VisualSVN works with 2010 about 5 minutes ago.

Comment: I just installed it to play around with it, haven't thought the consequences fully though :)

Answer (score 0):

If you need a gui use [TortoiseGit](http://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/)

If you can use the command line [Msysgit](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/) is the most mature standalone git client for windows.

[Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) also provides stable git command line support for windows.

Comment: I've found Git Source Control Provider to be much easier to use compared to TortoiseGIT, as it has superb integration into Visual Studio 2010.